# How do I create a Live Support chat application in C#?

Tags: c#, wcf, chat

I'm attempting to build a live support chat application in C# using a WCF microservice and after endless searches I still can't find the answer, hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction.

My problem is that rather than a typical chat room a where users broadcast messages to all connected clients, I need the application to be more like a Live Support app found on websites such as Amazon or eBay.

Ideally multiple customer support agents will have a pre installed WinForms chat application on their machines, when a customer opens a chat window (aspx page) it will connect to a server/service and the server/service will then call all connected customer support agents until one answers. At this point the customer and agent will be connected in a private chat window.

Could somebody please give me some insight or ideas on how to do this?

Thanks,

Owen

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASP.NET SignalR which is a library for ASP.NET developers that makes developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available.

[Here](http://www.asp.net/signalr) you can find more details and many tutorials about SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

The first resoult in google

[A WCF-WPF Chat Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25261/A-WCF-WPF-Chat-Application)

[Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCX0jP0Upsk)

[WCF Chat Application](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/componentdevelopment/article.php/c13197/WCF-Chat-Application.htm)

[ASP.NET Chatting using WCF Services and JSon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265695/ASP-Net-chatting-using-WCF-Services-and-JSon)

[A simple peer to peer chat application using WCF netPeerTcpBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17321/A-simple-peer-to-peer-chat-application-using-WCF-n)

usefull lectures
[HTML 5 Web Sockets](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/25c78a/html-5-web-sockets/)

Always first ask google, above you have few ready to use projects that you can copy to your solution

> EDIT:

Also as tip I can recommend  bi-directional message queues at application level, then make index for messages with session and users identifier. Next step would be WCF with pop and push logic based on wait objects. At low cost you will need to lock queue. WCF will do heavy job. Also problems can occure inside app with proxy management and message sending so dedicated proxy for chat would be great and safest idea. And read about Duplex Services that can be usefull here [DUPLEX SERVICE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I agonized with myself before posting here because of these kind of responses and down votes without explanations. All of these are chat rooms that broadcast messages to all connected clients, which is not what I am looking for. I need a solution where a customer calls ALL connected clients, but when one answers their chat becomes private.

Comment: @WelshWatson just take for example WCF Chat applications, change logic and here you go, you can use SignalR like someone said to get notifikaction, or implement our own obsersers. Your post is like my answere now. We dont know:  **what your have**, **what infrastracture youe have** but ok let my edit my post including guess, and remember stackoverlow is not like forums, we are not chatty, we are here to help you solved problem. If you write good questions you will get good answere :)

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you for the correction I always wondered why posts were taken down and down voted so easily. The edit is very helpful, thanks :)

Comment: @WelshWatson I call this StackNazi, if you want to avoid downvoting even with very simple question always give some code, and "what have your tried" :)

Comment: Lol that seems accurate. I'll be sure to do that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

These are my findings, not checked though:

[Live Support Chat using SignalR](https://sourceforge.net/projects/livesupportchat/)

[Parle](https://github.com/parle-io/parle)

A tutorial from ASP.NET team:

[Real-time chat with SignalR 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

The first one looks very early development stage, Parle is somewhat more promising.

Anyway, since I continue my research on the topic maybe I'd need to augment my answer. Until then the links could be a good starting point.